# multiply CIImage by scalar

Tags: swift, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

I'm working with a `CIImage` which I need to normalize by subtracting 128 and then dividing by 128 each pixel. How can I do this probably with `CIFilter`

Comment: This could result in negative values. Are you sure this is what you want to achieve?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel yes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but maybe you can apply two blend passes with static colors, like this:

```
let gray = CIImage(color: .gray) // this should be 50% white, or 128/255
let subtracted = CIBlendKernel.subtract.apply(foreground: gray, background: inputImage)!
let normalized = CIBlendKernel.divide.apply(foreground: gray, background: subtracted)
```

Keep in mind that you’d need to set the working format of your CIContext to something that supports negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in vImage (assuming your source pixels are `UInt8` and the destination pixels are `Float`), but rather using math to convert from 0...255 to -1...1, use a lookup table:

1. Use [`ramp`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/reading_from_and_writing_to_core_video_pixel_buffers) to create a lookup table of 256 `Float` values from -1 to +1.
2. Create a vImage buffer that references your image data but has a width that's the image width multiplied by the number of channels (e.g 2560 for an RGBA 640 wide image).
3. Create a 32-bit per channel vImage buffer with the same width as the destination.
4. Use [`vImageLookupTable_Planar8toPlanarF`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/reading_from_and_writing_to_core_video_pixel_buffers) to populate the destination with the `UInt8` pixels transformed to -1...+1 single-precision values.

You can wrap all that code up in a `CIImageProcessorKernel` to integrate it into your CI workflow. See: *[Reading From and Writing to Core Video Pixel Buffers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/reading_from_and_writing_to_core_video_pixel_buffers)*.